# Access userdata content in Corona SDK

Tags: c, lua, coronasdk

From an in-app server, I receive a table and inside this table there's a key marked as `userdata`. I red this type is there to allow arbitrary C data to be stored inside Lua variables. Is it possible to read/access its content from Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua can't read data from userdata, unless you write native functions that will read and return bytes from userdata in some way you will find convenient - as array of numbers, as string, or maybe just returning single byte at specified index.
Maybe your host app/framework already has these functions, but Lua itself definitely can't do that.
Corona SDK's page for userdata only quotes Lua's doc, telling basically the same - there's no operations on userdata in Lua, except assignment and identity test.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I never noticed there was a Lua userdata type, I thought it was a Corona-specific type